# mySQL Insert Into with Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, distinct

I have a workflow table which has `patient_id`, `pat_firstname`, `pat_lastname` data in it. I want to extract this data into a patient table.

```
INSERT INTO patients (patient_id, first_name, last_name)
SELECT DISTINCT patient_id, pat_firstname, pat_lastname
FROM workflow
```

The problem I am having is that this doesn't work because patient_id is the primary key in the patients table and some first_name fields or last_name fields don't match so there's duplicates trying to be inserted.

What I want is to just use any of the records from the workflow table for a first_name and last_name. For example, if there's:

`patient_id = 2`
`pat_first_name = Kris`
`pat_last_name = Doman`

`patient_id = 2`
`pat_first_name = Kristofer`
`pat_last_name = Doman`

I want to insert either record, it doesn't matter. How can I accomplish this in a single insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

use `INSERT IGNORE` : this will not modify already existing values

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO patients (patient_id, first_name, last_name)
SELECT DISTINCT patient_id, pat_firstname, pat_lastname
FROM workflow
```

or you can use `REPLACE` : this will either insert, either update the datas.

```
REPLACE INTO patients (patient_id, first_name, last_name)
SELECT DISTINCT patient_id, pat_firstname, pat_lastname
FROM workflow
```

If saving ressources matters, `REPLACE` is not recommended.

check the mysql documentation for details about `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `REPLACE`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Could you please provide examples of each?

Comment: This actually worked great with REPLACE :) I didn't realize this existed, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use GROUP BY to do this for you. You can change your SELECT portion of the query as follows:

```
SELECT patient_id, pat_firstname, pat_lastname
FROM workflow
GROUP BY patient_id
```